# How to do source control with Pentaho Report Designer?

Tags: version-control, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

We are using Pentaho Report Designer (PRD) to build out some PDFs and Excel files to the customer. Does anyone have a good strategy for doing version control on these reports? The prpt files seem to be a zipped set of xml. Is there a better format so we can tell what changed from one commit to another?

Answer (score 1):

It is a pain. That's the only format.

You can get pre to work with unzipped archives I believe. But the only way you're going to get nice version control is to unzip before you commit. And re zip on checkout or update.

Answer (score 1):

When I inquire that from Pentaho support for my purposes they said such feature is not there to maintain the version of PRD reports. Then they raised a JIRA request as a new feature.
[JIRA ticket](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/BISERVER-12684)

Answer (score 0):

In your commit comment, plainly state what was changed. You won't be able to do a diff on it to see the changes, but by looking at the commits on it you can see what was changed, who made the change, and when.